# Merging shapefiles and saving them to file geodatabase using ogr2ogr?

Tags: shapefile, merge, ogr2ogr, file-geodatabase

I have multiple shapefiles. When it becomes one layer (one shapefile) the volume of shapefile gets over the limit of its capacity (I believe 4GB? is the limit of *.shp can have)

Therefore, I need to save them into FGDB using ogr2ogr

this is the code I came out with so far.

> for %f in (*disp_line.shp) do (if not exist test.gdb (ogr2ogr -progress --config shape_encoding "UTF-8" -f "filegdb" test.gdb %f -lco encoding="UTF-8") Else (ogr2ogr --config shape_encoding "UTF-8" -progress -f "filegdb" -update -append test.gdb %f -nln test_layer -lco encoding="UTF-8"))

when I see the result.. I get two layers.
[image]

t_sc1disp_line feture class has 20 rows and test_line has 286 rows
it is supposed to be 306 rows (20+286)..

What it means is that I have to merge the layers once again using QGIS or ArcGIS GUI tools.

Could you fix my weird OGR2OGR command?

Comment: Add `-nln test_line` to the first command of the loop as well. Now you create first layer with the default name and only after that append the rest of the layers into "test_line". Did you really use `-nln test_layer` and got `test_line`as a result?

Comment: @user30184 you are right just adding -nln test_line at the first loop solved the issue. thanks a lot. and of course i didn't use -nln test_layer for my command. i made up with the -nln tag the example above.

Comment: The shapefile limit is 2Gb, not 4Gb, for each file.

Comment: I am trying to do the same as OP. I am using the same value for -nln in both the first iteration command and all others (the only difference in the command used for all other iterations is the addition of "-update" and "-append" flags). And yet ogr2ogr is still placing each shapefile in a separate feature class, instead of a single feature class, within the gdb. Per this answer, it seems that what I am seeing is not correct behavior from ogr2ogr, is that correct? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359377/merge-with-ogr2ogr-creating-multiple-feature-classes-despite-consistent-nln-fla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base on on @user30184 the code should be changed to

> for %f in (*disp_line.shp) do (if not exist test.gdb (ogr2ogr -progress --config shape_encoding "UTF-8" -f "filegdb" test.gdb %f -nln test_line -lco encoding="UTF-8") Else (ogr2ogr --config shape_encoding "UTF-8" -progress -f "filegdb" -update -append test.gdb %f -nln test_line -lco encoding="UTF-8"))